# Angularjs radio buttons are not selected with names

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My radio buttons are generated with a JSON array. JSFidle is created here "jsfiddle.net/deborad/8j9b4a7q/4/". Items having same value for attribute called 'group' are required be grouped together. That means, in the fiddle, if one radio button is selected from the checkboxes having group 'A', the other one should be unselected(same A group) and those (group A items) should be independant from items having value 'B' for attribute 'group' .

Problem is all checkboxes are responding as having same name. If a checkboxes in group B is selected, and I select a checkbox in group A, first item in group B is unselected. How I can solve this ?  Also I want to separately keep selected checkbox values from group A and group B. Any solution please.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle to work. Seems like it was using the string "item.group" rather than the value of the group key for the item object. [See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8j9b4a7q/7/)

You should use `{{item.group}}` rather than just item.group when binding in the html.

Comment: Thanks very much. It works in fiddle.. But one problem in my real app. My app handles 200 of such instances, and when the same code snip applied, more checkboxes in one group can be selected . Will there be a possible reason ?

Comment: I accidentally removed your original ng-checked verification. I edited the fiddle link in my answer above to have your original ng-checked verification.

Comment: Yep. But in this http://jsfiddle.net/deborad/8j9b4a7q/4/, I tried and it works there well with ng-checked. Same as in my app. It works for fiddle, but not in my app.. :(

Comment: So just to clarify, you want a similar functionality with checkboxes? Or is it still radio buttons where this is happening? My guess would be that the checked verification expression in ng-checked is where the issue might be.

Comment: RadioButtons. I don't use checkboxes. In my fiddle, there is only a very simple part. Actually, there is a outer array and it is iterated, finally internal array is iterated. The internal array 's functionality is shown in the fiddle. First time loading is ok. But when one radio button is clicked, other already selected one is also remained selected. :(

Comment: I would look into both the group names produced for each radio button and the ng-checked validation expression